# ContentProvider gives Unknown URI error

Tags: android, null, android-contentprovider

I've created my own ContentProvider and all but I am unsure of how to retrieve it. I keep getting a null when calling the getType method.

Here is my code:
CurrentPlacesMetaData class:

```
public static final String AUTHORITY = "healthcare.management.elderly.providers.CurrentPlacesContentProvider";
public static final String CONTENT_TYPE_PLACES_LIST = "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.healthcare.places";
public static final String CONTENT_TYPE_PLACES_ONE = "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.healthcare.places#";
```

CurrentPlacesContentProvider class:

```
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" 
        + CurrentPlacesMetaData.AUTHORITY + "/currentplaces");
static {
     sUriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
     sUriMatcher.addURI(CurrentPlacesMetaData.AUTHORITY, "places", PLACES_TYPE_LIST);
     sUriMatcher.addURI(CurrentPlacesMetaData.AUTHORITY, "places/#", PLACES_TYPE_ONE);
}
@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    switch(sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case PLACES_TYPE_LIST:
            return CurrentPlacesMetaData.CONTENT_TYPE_PLACES_LIST;
        case PLACES_TYPE_ONE:
            return CurrentPlacesMetaData.CONTENT_TYPE_PLACES_ONE;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
    }
}
```

Method to try call the ContentProvider:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://healthcare.management.elderly.providers.CurrentPlacesContentProvider/currentplaces/places");
String str = context.getContentResolver().getType(uri)
```

I get a null for str which probably tells that the uri is not recognised. So where have I gone wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URI contains `currentplaces` as the last part while in uri matcher you are matching  `places`

You can use the following format for uri matching of content providers

```
private static final String AUTHORITY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
private static final String COMMENT_BASE_PATH = "comment";

private static final int COMMENT = 100;
private static final int COMMENT_ID = 101;


public static final Uri URI_COMMENT = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/" + COMMENT_BASE_PATH);

private static final UriMatcher sURIMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
static {
    sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, COMMENT_BASE_PATH , COMMENT);
    sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, COMMENT_BASE_PATH + "/*" , COMMENT_ID);
}
```

And then you can just refer the  `URI_COMMENT`  wherever you like.

Answer (score 1):

You can call ContentProvider using,

```
Cursor c = managedQuery(uri, null, null, null, null);
```

But as now managedQuery is deprecated you have to use [`CursorLoader`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#managedQuery%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29). Here is an example for using [`CursorLoader`](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_loading-data_cursorloader/).

Comment: +1 but *have to* :) There is no problem at all if we use Deprecated stuffs.